# How to prevent clicking on last child angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to swap this video position

[image]

and this is the html

```
<div class="parent" #mainGrid (click)="onClick($event)">
  <div #cards class="cards div1">
    <plyr muted="true" plyrPoster="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.jpg"
      [plyrOptions]="optionsPlay" plyrTitle="Main Video" [plyrSources]="videoSources" (plyrInit)="player = $event"
      (plyrPlay)="played($event)" (plyrPause)="paused($event)" (plyrSeeked)="seeked($event)"
      (plyrEnterFullScreen)="enterFullscreen($event)"></plyr>
  </div>
  <div #cards class="cards div2">
    <plyr muted="true" plyrPoster="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.jpg"
      [plyrOptions]="options" plyrTitle="Video 2" [plyrSources]="videoSheet" (plyrInit)="player = $event"
      (plyrPlay)="played($event)" (plyrPause)="paused($event)" (plyrSeeked)="seeked($event)"></plyr>
  </div>
  <div #cards class="cards div3">
    <plyr muted="true" plyrPoster="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.jpg"
      [plyrOptions]="options" plyrTitle="Video 3" [plyrSources]="videoSources" (plyrInit)="player = $event"
      (plyrPlay)="played($event)" (plyrPause)="paused($event)" (plyrSeeked)="seeked($event)"></plyr>
  </div>
  <div #cards class="cards div4">
    <plyr muted="true" plyrPoster="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.jpg"
      [plyrOptions]="options" plyrTitle="Video 4" [plyrSources]="videoSheet" (plyrInit)="player = $event"
      (plyrPlay)="played($event)" (plyrPause)="paused($event)" (plyrSeeked)="seeked($event)"></plyr>
  </div>
  <div #cards class="cards div5">
    <plyr id="sheetVideo" plyrPoster="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.jpg"
      [plyrOptions]="optionsPlay" plyrTitle="Sheet Video" [plyrSources]="videoSheet" (plyrInit)="player = $event"
      (plyrPlay)="played($event)" (plyrPause)="paused($event)" (plyrSeeked)="seeked($event)"
      (plyrEnterFullScreen)="enterFullscreen($event)"></plyr>
  </div>
</div>
```

i found this helpful code for swapping the grid area https://codepen.io/naonvl/pen/KKmYmro and trying to implement that to my code, here's what i got so far

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.card = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.cards');
  }
  onClick(event ){
    console.log(event.target);
    this.card.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element)
    });
  }
```

but the problem is the  value of `event.target` is not the same as `element`

[image]

`event.target` value was the last child of `<plyr>` tag, but what i wanted is that `event.target` selecting the first `div` which contain the classes for grid area,how can i prevent that?

Comment: You can use a @ViewChildren to get those elements using #card instead of querying the elements

Comment: yes but still i can't get the first child, so im doing this `event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode` that gives me the parent `div` what do u think?

Comment: it's a bit dirty to do, what if you query the parent and get the childs? that should get you all those cards divs

Comment: but rn that code is giving me the value that i need, is there a correct way to do?

Comment: i think you're going through many params to get your value, that makes it a bit overcomplicate on an unnecessary way